# brotli gzip настройка в nginx

Tags: php, nginx, gzip, brotli

Использую brotli собранным в nginx

PHP 7.2.25
nginx 1.16.1
brotli 1.0.7

также использую PageSpeed собранный под nginx

config nginx

```
user bitrix;
worker_processes 8;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  10240;
}

http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/force-download;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    pagespeed on;  
    pagespeed FileCachePath /var/cache/nginx;  
    pagespeed FileCacheCleanIntervalMs -1;
    pagespeed RewriteLevel CoreFilters;
    pagespeed Domain https://site.ru;
    pagespeed EnableFilters remove_comments,convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp,collapse_whitespace;
    pagespeed InPlaceResourceOptimization on;
    
    pagespeed Statistics on;
    pagespeed StatisticsLogging on;
    pagespeed LogDir /var/log/pagespeed;
    pagespeed AdminPath /pagespeed_admin;
    pagespeed EnableCachePurge on;
    pagespeed PurgeMethod PURGE;
    pagespeed MessageBufferSize 100000;

    pagespeed Disallow "*/order/*";
    
    brotli  on;
    brotli_comp_level   6;
    brotli_static   on;
    brotli_types    text/plain text/css text/xml application/x-javascript;
    

    # Description of supported access log formats
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local - $upstream_response_time] '
                  '$status "$request" $body_bytes_sent '
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    log_format common '$remote_addr - - [$time_local - $upstream_response_time] '
                    '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $msec';

  log_format balancer '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_iso8601] "$host" '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "schema: $scheme" '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                    '"$request_length" : "$request_time" -> $upstream_response_time';

    log_format debug '$upstream_response_time,"$time_local","$remote_addr","$request",$status,$body_bytes_sent';


  # upload default maps
  include bx/maps/*.conf;

  # settings files
  include bx/settings/*.conf;

    # Disable request logging in nginx by default
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  common;
    access_log          off;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    client_max_body_size        1024m;
    client_body_buffer_size     4m;

    # Parameters for back-end request proxy
    proxy_connect_timeout       300;
    proxy_send_timeout      300;
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_buffer_size       64k;
    proxy_buffers           8 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size  10m;

    # Assign default error handlers
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    error_page 404 = /404.html;

    # Content compression parameters
    gzip                on;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_static         on;
    gzip_http_version       1.0;
    gzip_types          application/x-javascript application/javascript text/css;

    # add_header
    include bx/conf/http-add_header.conf;

    # Set default website
    include bx/site_enabled/*.conf;

    # Set additional websites
    include bx/site_ext_enabled/*.conf;
        
}
```

на кроне использую php скрипт

```
<?php
if(PHP_SAPI != 'cli')
{
    die();
}
function scan_recursive($directory)
{
    $directory = realpath($directory);
    if ($d=opendir($directory))
    {
        while($fname=readdir($d))
        {
            if ($fname=='.' || $fname=='..')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                $file = $directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fname;
                if(is_file($file))
                {
                    $ext = pathinfo($file,  PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if($ext == 'css' or $ext == 'js')
                    {
                        $make_br = $make_gz = true;
                        if(file_exists($file.'.br'))
                        {
                            $o = filemtime($file);
                            $c = filemtime($file.'.br');
                            if($o > $c)
                            {
                                unlink($file.'.br');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $make_br = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if(file_exists($file.'.gz'))
                        {
                            $o = filemtime($file);
                            $c = filemtime($file.'.gz');
                            if($o > $c)
                            {
                                unlink($file.'.gz');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $make_gz = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if($make_br)
                        {
                            $cmd = 'brotli -f -k -q 11 '.$file;
                            echo $cmd;
                            echo "\n";
                            echo shell_exec($cmd);
                            echo "\n";
                        }
                        if($make_gz)
                        {
                            $cmd = 'gzip -f -c -9 '.$file.' > '.$file.'.gz';
                            echo $cmd;
                            echo "\n";
                            echo shell_exec($cmd);
                            echo "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (is_dir($directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fname))
            {
                scan_recursive($directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fname);
            }
        }
        closedir($d);
    }
}
echo 'Start'."\n";
scan_recursive(__DIR__.'/bitrix/cache/');
scan_recursive(__DIR__.'/bitrix/js/');
scan_recursive(__DIR__.'/bitrix/css/');
scan_recursive(__DIR__.'/bitrix/templates/');
scan_recursive('/var/cache/nginx');
echo 'Finish'."\n";
```

заголовки которые приходят на файл brotli, а нужен content-encoding: br

```
cache-control: max-age=31536000
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 30940
content-type: application/javascript
date: Wed, 07 Oct 2020 15:45:45 GMT
etag: "5f7dbe36-78c0"
expires: Thu, 07 Oct 2021 15:45:45 GMT
server: nginx/1.16.1
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-original-content-length: 30912
```

Как настроить конфиг что бы если, есть файл brotli отдать brotli, если нет brotli, но есть gzip отдать gzip, если нет и того и другого отдать обычный?

Comment: Как я понял, скрипт готовит сжатые gzip и бротли статические файлы. Плюс Nginx настроен на сжатие бротли. Получается какая-то дичь: файл сжимается сначала скриптом, а потом еще nginx его на лету пережимает? Или нет, не ясно как Nginx настроен, смотрит ли он сначала сжатые версии файлов на диске, и если их нет - пережимает на лету? Плюс напишите какие заголовки кидаются когда идет такая белиберда.

Comment: @TotalPusher обновил пост, добавил ответы и конфиг

Comment: Сохраните проблемный файл с белибердой в виде файла, курлом или через браузер. Потом выполните `file <ваш сохраненный файл>`. Для brotli-формата утилита `file` выдаст "data", а для gzip "gzip compressed data". Я уверен, что отдастся "data" (то есть бротли), а вот в заголовке стоит "content-encoding: gzip" (а должен быть Content-Encoding: br). Если я прав, получается что проблема с заголовком - для бротли отдается gzip, что не верно. Таким образом проблема будет локализована. Ну а как поправить конфиг будем думать дальше.

Comment: @TotalPusher все верно 
`file pt.js`
`pt.js: data`
Как настроить конфиг что бы, если есть brotli, то отдать brotli , если нет - отдать gzip, если нет, то отдать обычный

Comment: Я с модулем `pagespeed` знаком очень поверхностно, единственное впечатление от него осталось - глючит и требует хорошей настройки. Подозреваю, что он конфликтует с инструкциями `brotli ...`. Попробуйте временно убрать директивы `pagespeed ...` и посмотреть - отдается бротли норм или нет? Также я думаю, что `brotli ...` директивы не нужно настраивать в конфиге nginx так как сейчас сделано, а воспользоваться настройками pagespeed и включить его там, и тогда этот модуль сам будет включать бротли без явного прописывания в конфиге Nginx как это сделано сейчас.

Comment: PS. Вот возьмите на заметку как можно быстро посмотреть заголовок бротли `curl -isSH "accept-encoding: br" https://www.brotli.pro | grep -ai 'content-encoding'`

Comment: Походу, да, pagespeed и бротли не совместимы. Вот [тут](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/install-nginx-with-brotli-module-in-centos-redhat-amzn-linux) написано: `As it stands, the PageSpeed NGINX module does not support Brotli compression internally. You can use if together with Brotli NGINX module, but you will have to disable internal PageSpeed compression via: pagespeed HttpCacheCompressionLevel 0;`. То есть нужно сделать `HttpCacheCompressionLevel 0;`

Comment: @TotalPusher Спасибо, буду тестить

Comment: PS. Напишите о результате. А так как `pagespeed HttpCacheCompressionLevel 0;` то gzip сжатие также нужно будет включить на уровне конфига Nginx, а не модуля. Тогда, по идее, все должно работать как надо.

Comment: @TotalPusher хорошо написал же, оформи ответ (он будет полезным даже если его не примут)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PageSpeed и brotli частично не совместимы. Вот что написано [в блоге](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/install-nginx-with-brotli-module-in-centos-redhat-amzn-linux):

> PageSpeed module compatibility
>
> As it stands, the PageSpeed NGINX module does not support Brotli compression internally.
>
> You can use if together with Brotli NGINX module, but you will have to disable internal PageSpeed compression via:
>
> `pagespeed HttpCacheCompressionLevel 0;`
>
> This will ensure that the Brotli compression works, at the cost of storing optimized assets uncompressed.

Таким образом, нужно отключить компрессию pagespeed через опцию:

```
pagespeed HttpCacheCompressionLevel 0;
```

В этом случае бротли будет работать.

Проверить можно таким образом, только подставьте свой адрес:

```
curl -isSH "accept-encoding: br" https://www.brotli.pro | grep -ai 'content-encoding'
```

если `br` - сработала компрессия бротли.

После такой доработки для `accept-encoding: gzip`, скорее всего, также потребуется [включение компреcсии в nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html) (посмотрите ещё [сюда](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html))

```
gzip                on;
gzip_types          text/plain text/css text/xml application/xml application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json; 
gzip_http_version   1.1;
gzip_comp_level     8;
gzip_min_length     1500;
gzip_buffers        32 8k;
gzip_proxied        any;
gzip_disable        msie6;
```